# Android Parse. Getting Data More Efficiently?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am Creating a small app, where each owner of the app can tap a button and increment the number on screen by one. The idea is that each app is connected and each user can see the same number so it updates on all devices. I decided to use the Parse SDK to store the Number online to be accessible on all devices. I have a simple button, that uses the following code when pressed:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            query.getInBackground("SQrRpfRBZW",
                    new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseObject num, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                taps.setText(String.valueOf(num
                                        .getInt("Num") + 1));

                                count = num.getInt("Num");
                                num.put("Num", count + 1);
                                num.saveInBackground();
                            } else {
                                // ERROR
                            }
                        }
                    });
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Then, I have a runnable, that is supposed to get the current value that is stored online every 500ms and update it on screen:

```
// RUNNABLE FOR UPDATES
    handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            query.getInBackground("SQrRpfRBZW",
                    new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseObject num, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                taps.setText(String.valueOf(num
                                        .getInt("Num")));
                            } else {
                                // ERROR
                            }
                        }
                    });

            handler.postDelayed(this, 200);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 100);
}
```

When I run the app, the number updates when I press the Button, but it is extremely slow, and the Garbage Collector is doing a lot of work.

Is there a more efficient way to Send and Retrieve the Data more quickly using Parse? And what am I doing wrong in regards to the Garbage Collector? I don't think im creating many new Objects.

Thank You Very Much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The garbage collection issues may be coming from the fact that you are creating a new runnable object every 200 milliseconds and then putting it on the android message queue.

And I think a much more efficient way of notifying users when the number has been updated is to force the server to push notifications instead of having the phone query the server. You should use GCM for this. Parse even has built in ability for it.

I think ultimately, you should create a parse cloud function that you call every time a user presses the button, and in that cloud function, you push down a notification to all the other users that the number has updated and that they need to query the server.

Comment: Just a clarification: The runnable object is not created every 200ms, the GetCallback object is :)

Comment: @JorgeGalvão I am not sure what you mean. We the code is creating both anonymous runnable and GetCallBack objects every 200ms. My understanding is that whenever you use the "new" keyword you are creating a new object and allocating space for it on the heap. In java, sometime after there aren't any more references to that memory allocation from any variable on the stack, the object is garbage collected. Therefore, in this scenario, (if my understanding is correct, the gc would have to constantly deallocate the memory for the runnable and GetCallBack objects being created.

Comment: The Runnable object is just created the first time.
It is then reused and its method run() is called over and over again, but no other Runnable instance is created:
    handler.postDelayed(this, 200);

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call new Runnable or new Handler, or new GetCallback you are creating a new Object. A better way to do this is to create all of your callbacks ONCE in onCreate of your activity or fragment and reuse them over and over.

so your code would look something like

```
private Runnable mRunnable; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle mBundle) 
{
    super.onCreate(mBundle);

    mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {...}};

    //create all of your callbacks here and reuse them

}
```

And when you get ready to use that runnable you would do

```
handler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 100);
```

You never want to create objects outside of onCreate. Object memory allocation and creation is an expensive operation.